# Prevent Multiple Entry in Table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

I am confused and facing issue in getting output like below image
Required Output

[image: Required Output]

I have database table called number_status in which I am storing number online and offline history with timestamp. I required to get json response for display data in my android application like above image. I am able to get it like below function

```
  public function compareNumber($firstNumber, $secondNumber, $email, $date) {
        $response = array('code' => 0, 'error' => false);
        $endDate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime("+1 day", strtotime($date))) . " " . explode(" ", $date)[1];

        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT id FROM user WHERE email = ?");
        $stmt->bind_param("s", $email);
        $stmt->execute();
        $result = $stmt->get_result();
        if ($result->num_rows) {
            $user =  $result->fetch_assoc();            
            $user_id = $user['id'];
            $stmt->close();

            $response["received"]   = $date;
            $response["created_at"] = $date;
            $response["end"]        = $endDate;
            $response["code"]       = 1;

            $arr = $this->helperNumber($firstNumber, $date, $endDate, $user_id);
            $arr1 = $this->helperNumber($secondNumber, $date, $endDate, $user_id);

            $response["logs"] = array_merge($arr, $arr1);
        }

        return $response;
    }

    public function helperNumber($numberToSearch, $date, $endDate, $user_id) {
        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT number, number_status, status_time FROM number_status WHERE number = ? AND  user_id=? AND status_time > ? AND status_time < ? ORDER BY status_time DESC");
            $stmt->bind_param("iiss", $numberToSearch, $user_id, $date, $endDate);
            $stmt->execute();
            $result = $stmt->get_result();

            $number = array();
            if ($result->num_rows) {
                $lastrow = null;
                $i = 0;
                while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                    if(!isset($number[$i]))
                        $number[$i] = array('number' => $row['number'], 'start_time' => false, 'end_time' => false);

                    if($lastrow == null){
                        // take offline as first entry
                        if($row['number_status'] == 0) {
                            $number[$i]['end_time'] = $row['status_time'];
                        }
                    } else {
                        // if two repeated entry for online/offline skip it
                        if($lastrow['number_status'] == 0 && $row['number_status'] == 0) 
                            continue;
                        if($lastrow['number_status'] == 1 && $row['number_status'] == 1)
                            continue;

                        if($row['number_status'] == 1){
                            $number[$i]['start_time'] = $row['status_time'];
                        }
                        else  {
                            $number[$i]['end_time'] = $row['status_time'];  
                        }
                        if($number[$i]['start_time'] && $number[$i]['end_time'])
                            $i++;

                    }

                    $lastrow = $row;

                }

            }
            $stmt->close();
            return $number;
    }
```

I am getting json response for above function like below

```
{"code":1,"error":false,"received":"2018-07-15 00:00:00","created_at":"2018-07-15 00:00:00","end":"2018-07-16 00:00:00","logs":[{"number":"919400000001","start_time":"2018-07-15 16:11:04","end_time":"2018-07-15 16:12:03"},{"number":"919400000001","start_time":"2018-07-15 10:35:47","end_time":"2018-07-15 10:37:34"},{"number":"919400000001","start_time":"2018-07-15 10:31:03","end_time":"2018-07-15 10:33:43"},{"number":"919400000001","start_time":"2018-07-15 10:27:28","end_time":"2018-07-15 10:27:46"},{"number":"919400000001","start_time":"2018-07-15 10:26:55","end_time":"2018-07-15 10:27:26"},{"number":"919400000001","start_time":"2018-07-15 10:25:38","end_time":"2018-07-15 10:25:50"},{"number":"919400000001","start_time":"2018-07-15 10:24:51","end_time":"2018-07-15 10:25:14"},{"number":"919400000000","start_time":"2018-07-15 10:55:18","end_time":"2018-07-15 16:11:04"},{"number":"919400000000","start_time":"2018-07-15 10:33:50","end_time":"2018-07-15 10:34:04"},{"number":"919400000000","start_time":"2018-07-15 10:27:20","end_time":"2018-07-15 10:27:38"},{"number":"919400000000","start_time":"2018-07-15 10:25:42","end_time":"2018-07-15 10:25:57"},{"number":"919400000000","start_time":"2018-07-15 10:24:57","end_time":"2018-07-15 10:25:22"}]}
```

But I want sort it by end time (offline). I do not have idea how I can do it. In my database table there separate entry for online(start_time) and offline(end_time). Let me know if someone can help me for get it.
Thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The below might do what you are looking for - but it will involve some changes to your PHP code.

```
select number, min(start_time), end_time 
from (
  select t1.number as number, 
         t2.status_time as start_time, 
         min(t1.status_time) as end_time 
  from number_status t1 
    inner join number_status t2
      on 
          t1.number=t2.number and 
          t1.number_status=0 and 
          t2.number_status=1 and 
          t1.status_time > t2.status_time and
          t1.user_id=t2.user_id
  where 
     (t1.number=? or t1.number=?) AND 
     t1.user_id=? AND 
     t2.status_time > ? AND t1.status_time < ?
  group by t1.number, t2.status_time ) t
GROUP BY number, end_time
ORDER BY end_time DESC;
```

The query works as follows:
First, the inner join of the number_status table with itself creates a list of entries with number, start_time and end_time (t1 label for end_time, t2 label for start_time).  With the join conditions, this will include every possible start_time from t2 and every possible end_time from t1 that is greater than the start_time.

The where part restricts the set of numbers, user_id and status_time values.
The group by (t1.number, t2.status_time) alongside the min(t1.status_time) from the select leaves only those records that have the same start_time and the same number and the smallest possible end_time.

The surrounding select has two objectives:
First, for each end_time pick the smallest start_time available (again the group by and min);
Second, order the result by end_time (in this case, I chose DESC - but ASC is also possible).

I am certain that the same can also be done quite easily in PHP directly, but I would be at a loss as to how...

Comment: Please explain this code-only answer.  Always endeavor to educate when you post an answer.  Posting a correct solution is only the beginning of a "good" answer.